# Why abstract method access modifiers don't need to be honoured by the implementer class?

Tags: typescript

In the following scenario I have an abstract class with abstract methods that hold the `protected` access modifier (which of course I want to respect).

The thing is that, the class that implements the abstract one, can either honour this access modifier or not. The compiler seems not to bother in enforcing it. Full example below:

```
abstract class AbstractClass {
    protected abstract methodOne(): void;
    protected abstract methodTwo(): void;
}

class ImplementationClass extends AbstractClass {
    protected methodOne(): void {
        // doing something.
    }
    public methodTwo(): void {
        // doing something else.
    }
}

class App {
    instance: ImplementationClass;

    constructor() {
        this.instance = new ImplementationClass();
        this.instance.methodOne();
        this.instance.methodTwo();
    }
}
```

As you can see from the code, `methodOne` implementation respects the access modifier, but `methodTwo` doesn't (it is `public`). Therefore, in my `App` class, the compiler correctly complains that `methodOne` is protected and only accessible within class `ImplementationClass`, whereas for `methodTwo`, invokation is completely legal for the compiler.

Am I missing something very fundamental? Shouldn't this be also an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design and it happens for any member not just abstract ones. The derived class can specify the `public` access modifier if the base class species `protected`. You can't override `private` members regardless of acces modifier.

You can see [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4672) GitHub issue for details

Comment: I see, and I can confirm that if implementing it with the `private` modifier it gives a compilation error. Btw, is there any thread you know where this has been discussed? I'd like to learn more about the background of this decision. Thanks!

Comment: @marcofo88 Updated the answer.